# Akka HTTP Set Response Headers

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have an Akka route like this:

```
val searchRoutes = pathPrefix("api" / "search") {
    searchByParam 
}
def searchByParam = get {
    parameters('searchKey.as[String]) { searchKey =>
      complete {
        searchByKeyword(searchKey)
      }
    }
  }
```

When I make a request, it just works with a header of text/plain but I want my API works with header Accept: application/json
How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to set response headers for your route. Look into [`respondWithHeaders`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/respond-with-directives/respondWithHeaders.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set request header, not the response header.

Comment: Are you asking how the client can set the header or how the server can update the headers after the request has been received?

Comment: It is simple, the client can call this API with Accept: text/plain only. I want to make an API which the client can call with Accept: application/json. This clearly needs some code update at server side to support that, that is my question.

Comment: See [header directives](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.11/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/index.html) if what you're looking for is a way to *require* certain client headers exist in the request. Each of the directives will reject the request if the header you require isn't found, and you can apply additional logic to verify the header value matches what you expect it to be.